# Vector to raster with name of species

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, raster-conversion

I am dealing with polygons of species almost 500. I convert them into raster of 1km by 1km resolution to know the presence of species in each cell. When I convert them into raster they give me total number in each cell like 45, 65 species in each cell of raster.

Is it possible they give me the name of species too which species were found in which cell. Attach below picture 1 only give me option of numeri's such as id etc.   But form picture 2 attribute table, from which I want the binomial in my raster file. Is it possible to get such in qgis?
Picture 1..This highlighted section doesn't option for what i want from second picture.
[image]
picture 2
[image]

Comment: I would keep it in vector format with the species as columns. Create a square vector grid, spatial join the observations to each grid, pivot the table

Comment: instruction unclear ... maybe try to make a multi band raster with 1 band = 1 specie and boolean values ?

Comment: This is possible in ArcGIS, where the raster stores the numeric values and a raster attribute table stores the text values, however QGIS does not support raster attribute tables (yet), so this is not currently possible.